# Can't change table and column settings in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I' trying to change the settings of a column but most of the options in te properties are disabled.
What could be the problem?

For example, I want my primary key to be incremented automatically (for some reason it wasn't automatically like that).

Comment: Could be you don't have rights to change the table.    What error message do you get if you try to make the changes using tSQL and ALTER TABLE commands?

Comment: Is your column type an int or bigint?